# Java HTTPSession -- Storing User email as String vs. Storing User Object

Tags: java, jsp, object, jstl, httpsession

I have an HTTPSession object and I would like to store user information in it.

I have two options

- Storing the user email as a String and get the user out of the database and use the fields every time.
- Store the User object in the session and get JSTL support, for example I can do ${User.firstName}

Which one is a better solution? Best practice?

Answer (score 2):

I think storing as the object will be the better one...

Answer (score 1):

It all depends if you expect the user information to change during the life-time of the session or not.

If it doesn't change, or you don't care displaying stale values, storing the user in the session is fine. Else, getting the latest user information every time from the database is necessary.

I would avoid identifying a user by his email address, though, as it's something that can expire and change. Use a technical user ID, and store his email as any other information of the user.

Answer (score 0):

I would be careful about storing large objects in the session as it can become a performance bottleneck. The full object might be the more comfortable solution BUT if the object you are storing is large you can run into memory and performance problems because the object is serialized and deserialized. This also implies you can only store objects in the session which are serializable (means they need to implement the Serializable interface).

I always try to store as little as possible in the session. In your case just store the identifier and lookup the user object later e.g. using some utility method.